# Access View from Timer or Handler

Tags: android, timer, delay, repeat

App crashes, I am unable to use the same view in Timer Class

I need the app to refresh  a value and display it

```
Timer t = new Timer();
//Set the schedule function and rate
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)
                                  find(v);
                              }

                          },
//Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
            0,
//Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
            10000);

public void find(View view) {
    if (btAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        //the button is pressed when it discovers, so cancel the discovery
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    } else {
        BTArrayAdapter.clear();
        btAdapter.startDiscovery();

        registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you try find(null) instead of find(v), since you're not using the View anyway?

Comment: still crashes, apparently -- android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in this situation you need to use Activity.runOnUiThread()

```
 Timer t = new Timer();
//Set the schedule function and rate
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                          @Override
                          public void run() {
                             //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds   (1 second) (the period parameter)
                              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                  public void run() {find(v);}
                             });
                          }

                      },
//Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
            0,
//Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
            10000);
```

Comment: worked :D, i also had to declare View v as a global variable and used ur code

Comment: also, can u help me out to add this code to a serivce? i need this running even when the app is closed

Comment: that's beyond my knowledge unfortunately

Comment: Actually I think you might want an Alarm for that: http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/training/scheduling/alarms.html